# Redirect all Android traffic via VPN

Tags: android, vpn

I have a task to write an application that can redirect all traffic to Android via VPN. As I understand it can be included in the android through the settings, but i need to do it programmatically.

I learned VpnServis, and as I understood, with it I can create a application that can work with own created Vpn service, I can also assign vpn always on to other applications with the Vpn service created with it.

But I wonder if it is possible to do this for all installed applications, and if possible, how. And also interseting possibility assign vpn always on setting on all installed applications. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `VpnService`, you need to use `VpnService.Builder` to create it. While adjusting `VpnService.Builder` parameters, you need to assign what traffics you are interested in. This is done by adding a route through `addRoute()` method.

if you use `0.0.0.0/0` as your route, you will capture all traffic from all apps.

VPN always on is only supported from API level 24, so make sure if you want to use it. You need another approach (for example job) for creating this feature in lower API levels.